# Unable to sync to Ubuntu One after installing lxde and Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu-one, nautilus, lxde

I've just installed ubuntu 12.04 and added lxde as well as Nautilus. The downloading of my stored files has just started, but I'm unable to sync new folders via right-clicking. How can I solve the problem? I'd like to avoid GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. And in my case I had already synchronized a folder inside the folder I was trying to sync. This was overlapping, I just stopped the sync in the inside folder and then synchronize new folder in the upper level.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can either install ubuntuone-client-gnome which provides the Nautilus extension, or just use the control panel to sync new folders.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. ubuntone-client-gnome is already installed, yet just doesn't work...

Comment: Nothing comes to mind really. I suggest you file a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Comment: If you installed the package after Nautilus was already running, then nautilus will have to be restarted for the plug-in to load. Also, the folders must be underneath your home directory, and not be underneath a folder already being synchronized on U1.