# Problems after changing from PCManFM to Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, lubuntu, lxde, pcmanfm, lxpanel

I have to use LXDE because of the age of my system, and I quite like it. But after I changed the default file manager from PCManFM to Nautilus (via [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155897/how-to-make-nautilus-the-default-file-manager-in-lxde)) and restarted, I just get a background color and some of the logos; even then, some of the logos are different than the typical LXDE logos.

It says LXPanel is running when I run task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>) and when I try to run it from terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) it says that it is already running.

If I kill LXPanel via terminal and run the command `sudo lxpanel` it will run, but only as long as the command is running in terminal and even then the logos are weird on the panel too.

The original install was done via `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`, so hopefully that helps. I had some default LXDE programs installed and the LXDE DE.

**EDIT:**

I simply ran the command `sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get purge lxde` and then reinstalled it via `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install lxde*` (I know about the `*` and what it does, I wanted it that way.)

Anyways, it works now and I am using it currently. Thanks for the help @vasa1.

Comment: Is there anywhere you've described your original set-up? Was it a vanilla Lubuntu install? Why did you need to run `sudo lxpanel` and not simply `lxpanel`? I think you can run something from a terminal and have it running even after closing the terminal like this: `nohup lxpanel &`

Comment: Oh, my bad. I should have said something about that.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the post and as you can see, it is working fine now. Thanks for the help! I will stick with PCManFM and just start Nautilus when I need a feature.

Comment: Great! To my mind, the second command wouldn't be needed. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Which second command? The `sudo apt-get install lxde*`? It wanted to see the extra features that it might come with.

Comment: This: sudo apt-get install lxde*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my problem, I just had to purge and reinstall `LXDE` and `lubuntu-desktop`.

Actual commands:

1. `sudo apt-get purge lxde`
2. `sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-desktop`
3. `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`
4. `sudo apt-get install lxde*` (I know what the `*` option means, I wanted that)

Thanks for the edits and comments @vasa1